# What is the meaning of "ones" here?

Tags: plural-forms

1. A repeater is used to convert distorted signals into unidistorted **ones**.

Is it correct to use **ones**? Does **ones** here mean **signals**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, and it refers to the aforementioned 'signals'.

> **one**, *pronoun*
>
> **1** Used to avoid repeating a noun, when you are referring to
>   somebody/something that has already been mentioned, or that the person
>   you are speaking to knows about

Source, which offers examples: [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/one_2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does mean "signals", correct. "Signals" is the plural form of "signal", the extra "s" at the end shows you this. If it was "signal" then you would say "into an undistorted one". Of course here I had to use "an", this is because we have only one signal now, and saying "into undistorted one" wouldn't make sense. You'll understand these as time goes by, it will start to sound better and better as you learn.

It is important to note that "ones" IS NOT another word for "signals" though. Whoever wrote what you're reading could have used the word "signals" again instead of "ones", but decided to use "ones" to refer to them.